# Integral function and inequality

Tags: integration

Assume that we have:

$g(t)+\int_{t}^{T}f(s)ds\leq h(t)$ for all $0\leq t\leq T$

with $f$ is a positive increasing function.
Can me deduce or write

$g(t)+\int_{0}^{T}f(s)ds\leq h(t)$ for all $0\leq t\leq T$ ?

Comment: When ,we get $∫_{T/2}^{T }f(s)ds$$\leq $$∫_{t}^{T}f(s)ds$?

Answer (score 0):

No. To see that it does not work in general, if
$$
h(t)=g(t)+\int_t^T f(s)\,ds
$$
then the first inequality is satisfied, but, since $f\geq 0$,
$$
g(t)+\int_0^T f(s)\,ds > g(t)+\int_t^T f(s)\,ds=h(t)
$$
if $t>0$.